# dpkg: error processing <..>

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, dpkg

```
# dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/pve-firmware_1.0-14_all.deb
(Reading database ... 39867 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking pve-firmware (from .../pve-firmware_1.0-14_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/pve-firmware_1.0-14_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/RTL8192SU/rtl8192sfw.bin', which is also in package firmware-realtek 0.28+squeeze1
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/pve-firmware_1.0-14_all.deb
```

The installation of Debian 6 (amd64) is clean. How to investigate the problem deeper?

**Solved** by removing package firmware-realtek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, but the problem is in this:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/pve-firmware_1.0-14_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/RTL8192SU/rtl8192sfw.bin', which is also in package firmware-realtek 0.28+squeeze1
```

This means that the file `/lib/firmware/RTL8192SU/rtl8192sfw.bin` is part of these packages:

- `pve-firmware_1.0-14_all`
- `firmware-realtek 0.28+squeeze1`

If you don't need the alternate, just remove it:

```
apt-get remove firmware-realtek 0.28+squeeze1
```

Be careful when you try this: *look* at anything else that APT wants to remove, in case it is a set of important items like GNOME or worse.

Otherwise, you can force the package to overwrite the file with:

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install pve-firmware_1.0-14_all
```

Note that this *will* overwrite the file, and if you rely on the package `firmware-realtek 0.28+squeeze1` working and being intact, it might not. Your "new" version of the file might be older or newer and things may react badly; only do this last command if you *know* what you are doing.